# getTargetFragment().onActivityResult() doesn't dismiss the fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have fragment A, which calls fragment B with setTargetFragment. 
Once fragment B finishes certain operations, it calls getTargetFragment().onActivityResult().

It works fine(meaning, fragment A's callback onActivityResult is being invoked as it should) , but fragment B is not detached or removed. The user still stays on fragment B for some reason. How is that possible? shouldn't oActivityResult remove the fragment from the stack, or at least go away for the user to see fragment A again ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process is pretty much the same as in an activity which you need to call `finish()` after setting the result. In case of a fragment you should call `popBackStack()` to remove the current fragment, the same way you call `finish()` to pop the current activity.

Comment: so what's the difference between just using regular methods to transfer data between two fragment, and using the TargetFragment onActivityResult?
In both cases fragment manager's state doesn't change at all

Comment: Well, if you pop the back stack you won't be able to pass data to the previous fragment, the same way if in an Activity you just call finish(), you won't be passing any data for the previous Activity. Point is, you won't need to recreate/get the instance of any of these, just set a result and pop

Comment: It's really strange. I have 2 cases where I call the onActivityResult in fragment B. In one of them the onActivityResult removes fragment B, in the other one it doesn't and I have to call popBackStack. Do you happen to know why

Comment: If it "removes" and you are not calling popBackStack theres only one option: you are adding/replacing the fragment in the process, not removing the previous.